# How to describe "hyper-scared?"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, american-english

I am looking for a wider expression for someone who is hyper-scared of pain and things that cause pain. I came up with “afraid of as much as a needle,” but I get nowhere when I search for it on Google books. “Agliophobia” sounds too complex to me. Would an average teenager in the USA understand Agliophobia? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/petrified?s=t) defines ***petrified*** as:

> to benumb or paralyze with astonishment, horror, or other strong emotion:

In a sentence:

> Sarah is *petrified* from pain, she suffers from agliophobia.

Comment: @Syk If anything is unclear, or you need any further clarification, please let me know :D

Comment: Thanks for all your effort – I should have asked my question in a different way. What I wanted to know is if “afraid of as much as a needle” sounds (grammatically) okay in US English? She or he is not afraid only of pain, but also of things that seem that could cause him/her pain. Did you mean I should have used “Petrified of as much as a needle?”

Comment: @Syk _“afraid of as much as a needle`_ is not idiomatic. You might want to try _"afraid from a [hypodermic] needle"_ and then, yes _"petrified from a [hypodermic] needle"_ would be correct. In context, this would be:  **Can you believe 3kstc is _petrified from a [hypodermic] needle!_**

Comment: Thanks. The sentence in which I wanted to use it is “A boy, afraid of as much as a needle, fakes to be transgender to get his operation and keep his parent together.”
For some reason, this “Afraid of as much as a needle” sounded okay in my head. What I wanted to say – slip into the sentence is the risk – the consequence of what this boy is about to do to and so show his determination in his task.

Comment: @Syk if you like the answer please select the answer! :D thanks

Comment: I was hoping someone would answer me if Agliophobic is too complex for a simple-minded USA citizen.
Did you mean that “afraid of as much as a needle` is not idiomatic, specifically in the USA? I am sure I picked that from a TV show, but have no idea if it was, UK, Australia, or God knows which country.

Comment: @Syk I have never heard the phrase _"afraid of as much as a needle"_ and thereby I do not think it is idiomatic in any English. As for _agliophobic_ it's not commonly used, and I doubt any commoner would understand.

Comment: Thanks. I had to double-check it since, as I recently discovered, I cannot relate too much to Google books when it comes to such things.

Comment: @Syk "Afraid of as much as a needle" doesn't quite work. "Afraid of as *little* as a needle" might be better. Or "afraid of even a needle" is better still.

Comment: @3kstc "afraid from a needle" is not grammatical in any dialect of English I am aware of. Petrified **of** or **by** a needle.

Comment: @Syk I doubt many people will be familiar with the word agliophobic. I have never heard it before, but would probably work out what it meant with a bit of thought.

Comment: @Syk Also, you can't use "fakes" in that sentence. It should be "pretends to be"

Comment: @JamesRandom You're right, it should be _Can you believe 3kstc is petrified **of** a [hypodermic] needle!_

Answer (score 1):

Terrified is your best option if you want a word readily understood.

***[terrified](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/terrified)***

> very frightened:
>
> terrified (of somebody/something) to be terrified of spiders
>
> terrified (of doing something) I'm terrified of losing you.
>
> terrified (that…) He was terrified (that) he would fall.
>
> terrified (at something) She was terrified at the thought of being alone.
>
> You look absolutely terrified! She looked at him with wide, terrified eyes.

So you could say:

> Terrified of pain.

-- Oxford